# Google Cloud Shell - cannot connect - client network error

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Running Windows 10 home I keep getting the following error message when I try to open Google Cloud Shell in Chrome:

Cannot connect to Cloud Shell due to a client network error. Please ensure you are connected to the internet and your network proxy settings allow connections to Cloud Shell.

In Firefox it's this error message (incl. incognito mode): An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server. Check the server and the network configuration.

I have tried:

- Instances (VM on GCP/Compute Engine) in 2 different zones
- Switching off firewall
- Safe mode option for google cloud shell
- Restart google cloud shell
- Two different computers, on two different networks
- No proxy server marked in LAN settings
- Clearing cache on Chrome browser
- CMD as Admin netsh winsock reset
- CMD as Admin netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
- CMD as Admin netsh int ipv4 reset
- CMD as Admin SFC/Scannow
- CMD as Admin DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- Using Chrome SSH extension - SSH for Google Cloud Platform
- Connected through Tunnelbear VPN
- Applied latest Windows Update patch - November 27, 2018—KB4467682
- Deleted SSH keys in "Compute Engine -> Metadata"

Any suggestions are really appreciated!

Relevant troubleshooting link for others could be - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror

Answer (score 0):

More than an answer is a comment, if I understand you are try to open the Cloud Shell from the web browser, the browser is as not incognito mode?, disabling the default proxy configuration from your browser. Any relevant change from your firewall rule in the Win10 host?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I appreciate your time!
Initially it worked, and I haven't made any firewall changes since. However I had reset one of my routers, acting more or less like switch. I've also tryed connecting to the other router (wireless though) instead, with same result. I've also tryed to connect via VPN (Tunnelbear), to see if there was something with my router setup conflicting.

Comment: I tryed two browsers, firefox and Chrome, where I've also tryed firefox in incognito mode.
I haven't made any changes in Win 10 firewall. I'm also running Bullguard, which I haven't made any changes to either.

Answer (score 0):

I found that an Ad Blocker on my Firebox browser was preventing connection. If you disable it for Google Cloud then it works again.